# How to stop leaked DNS for VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have Loki and I use Private Internet Access for my VPN. I couldn't get PIA's client to work on Loki so I used [this method](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/robolinux) to install and it uses the network manager. It works great, but my DNS leaks. I tried using [this method](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html) to stop the leak, but I don't know where the .opvn file is I'm supposed to add the lines to. I tried adding it to this file

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PIA - [some country]`

But that didn't work. Any help?